# Store new line of data when values change in another cell(s) - change value macro

Tags: excel, vba, byval

I have a spreadsheet that has an add-in that is constantly feeding in data.  The data changes from time to time.  I need a macro that will create a new line item storing this data with a time stamp each time the value in any one of the 3 cells changes.

In cells J3, L3, N3 are the values that are feeding in live data that will change.  Whenever the value in J3, L3, or N3 changes I want the values in those cells to copy and paste values in a new line item in cells B, D, F with a time stamp added in column A.

I'm a novice so go easy on me.  Below is the code, which doesn't work because it only updates one column if one of the values changes, but I want all 3 values to get logged regardless if its only the data in J3, L3, N3 that change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$J$3" Then
SPOT1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & SPOT1).Value = 
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J3").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & SPOT2) = "=Now()"

End If

If Target.Address = "$L$3" Then
SPOT2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & SPOT2).Value = 
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L3").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & SPOT2) = "=Now()"

End If

If Target.Address = "$N$3" Then
Spot3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & Spot3).Value = 
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N3").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Spot3) = "=Now()"

End If

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried on your own? Please edit your question and post your code attempt and explain what's not working with your code in details. Please also understand SO is not a code writing service where you state your requirements and expect people to provide you a solution. You need to ask a specific programming question about your code (which you actually have not ask any yet)

Comment: Depending on exactly how updates occur you should be able to use a `worksheet_change` or `worksheet_Calculate` event handler for this.

Comment: I added the code that I have.  I'm a beginner so any guidance would help.  thanks.

Comment: I figured out getting it to work, but the way the Add In pulls in data it doesn't trigger the macro to recognize the change even though the value in the cell changes.  If I go into the cell and hit enter, then it works.  Does anyone know how to get excel to recognize the change?